# n dimensional array creator in Python

Tags: python

Is there any way I can make this function more inline?

```python
def nDimensionalArray(n, s):
    x = 0
    for i in range(n):
        x = [x for j in range(s[i])]
    return x
```

Comment: Cross-posted from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453596/n-dimensional-array-python)

Answer (score 3):

You didn't write a docstring (which you should have done) or explain your function (which you should also have done), but it looks like `n` is supposed to be the same as the length of `s`.  If so, why should `n` have to be specified?

Your function has some unintuitive behaviour:

```
>>> matrix = nDimensionalArray(3, [1,2,3])
>>> matrix
[[[0], [0]], [[0], [0]], [[0], [0]]]
>>> matrix[0][0][0] = 1
>>> matrix
[[[1], [1]], [[1], [1]], [[1], [1]]]
```

Changing one element changes everything!  I assume that that is unintentional.  If it is intentional, then it needs to be clearly documented.